# You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders when using react-native-reanimated

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, babeljs, metro-bundler

I have a React Native app that I generated using Expo. And when I installed `react-native-reanimated`, it gave me this error. Do I have to configure something else with it?

[image]

Comment: Could you please accept my answer if it's correct?

Answer (score 5):

Add babel plugin for `react-native-reanimated` to your `babel.config.js` as documented expo's [official page](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/reanimated/):

```
  module.exports = {
      ...
      plugins: [
          'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
          '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from',
          'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
      ],
  };
```

Comment: What's missing from this solution is that the plugin must be last

Comment: I'm going to retract what I just said, and the prior post (i made). I think there is something else going on. When following `expo install react-native-reanimated` suggestion, it changed package.json from 2.10.1 to 2.9.1 version and that works. Having plugin at end did not help.

Comment: This will not work for Web bundled applications.

Answer (score 4):

Simply, include the plugin in  `babel.config.js` of the react native project as

`@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from`,
`react-native-reanimated/plugin`,

The full code of `babel.config.js` is:

```
plugins: [
  '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from',
  'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
]
```

This works correctly for the react native application running on web.

Comment: This is the correct answer for web bundling. You need the additional babel plugin as described in the official Expo documentation here:  https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/reanimated/

Answer (score 4):

react-native-web seems to only work with `"react-native-reanimated": "2.9.1"`.  Expo when upgrading will install "~2.12.0".  This breaks web implementation.  Downgrading reanimated was the only way I found to fix it.

```html
yarn add react-native-reanimated@2.9.1

or 

npm i react-native-reanimated@2.9.1
```

Comment: This worked for me - React Native is truly a library with dependency hell. Looks to be a poorly managed ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

Install react native reanimated

```
expo install react-native-reanimated
```

Comment: Why does this work?

Comment: because It is a version problem,  for web, only 2.9.1 has no problem. 
 
`react-native-reanimated": "2.9.1" `